# android: Activity as a subscreen of a larger screen?

Tags: android, xml, mobile

I am hoping to save some time with a project and wonder if this is possible to do.

Currently there are some android phone screens that have already been developed by a former colleague.  I am developing a new screen for a tablet that needs to have the content of an existing screen that he developed appear as a sub-screen (say a little box in the bottom right corner of the screen.  This is aesthetically ok because the existing screen is small (phone).  The screen I am developing is for a 10.1" tablet, so it only takes up a tiny portion of my screen.

However, the problem is that he had the screen all coded up in a nicely and integrated with an associated Activity.  I am hoping to just reuse it by calling an Intent from my screen/activity unit, modifying it as  little as possible.

QUESTION:  Is it possible to have an activity appear as a subscreen of another activity?
Mind you I know that you can launch a fire and forget activity from one screen with an Intent + startActivity().  But that will only take the new screen appear on top of the old screen.

Where as I want the new screen to appear as a subscreen of the existing screen.  Any idea?

All pointers and recommendations are appreciated.  TIA

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html)!

From the Android documentation:

> A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an
>   Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to
>   build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. You
>   can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has
>   its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can
>   add or remove while the activity is running.

If you're developing for devices running Android versions prior to 3.0, take a look at the [compatibility library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html), which allows the use of Fragments in versions 1.6 onwards.

Further, if you're developing for phones and tablets, you can reuse the same Fragment in both interfaces.

Comment: Thanks David, that's exactly what I need to do "developing for phones and tablets".   We are trying to reuse existing codes and also to maintain one code source.

Comment: Great stuff! If you get stuck, I recommend that you take a look at the open source [Google IO](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/) Android app. There are several fragment examples in there, used in both tablet and phone form.

Comment: @spearfishman If you found this useful you can mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the green tick to the left.